# Menu not updating for logged in users after redirect

Tags: php, functions, menus, login, homepage

I'm having a problem with my menu not being updated for logged in users.
My website has a homepage which I want to change depending if you're logged in or not. I've done this by adding the following code to functions.php:

```
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( [3585] ) ) {
        wp_redirect('http://mysite.nl/subdomain');
        exit;
    }
}
```

This solution might not be ideal, but out of all the ones I could find, this one is the only one that actually works for me.

I also use the plugins "User Menus" and "If Menu" to have separate menu items visible for logged in and out users. 
However, after being redirected by the code above, the menu does not update - I can still only see the menu items one should see when logged out, even though I am logged in. Going to any other page does show the menu as it should be, it's just that this page does not. Is there anyone who has an idea why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it not redirect? I notice you have `is_page`, but you run your code on the `wp` hook, perhaps it's running too early? Would `is_home` not be more accurate?

Comment: It does redirect, but the menu won't change. `is_front_page` or `is_page` does not make a difference, but `is_home` does not redirect on the `wp` hook. I've tried other hooks as well while using `is_front_page`, but they don't redirect successfully or don't update the menu as well.

Comment: Welcome aboard. You may want to try [this post](https://www.isitwp.com/display-different-menus-for-logged-in-users/) to solve your problem.

Comment: Sadly, this also results in the menu not switching at all once logged in.

Comment: @ErkerDeBerker you might be confusing people talking about switching menus, what your code does is redirect. Perhaps if your code example involved menu APIs it might be accurate